# Can I use polyurethane to coat a painted wall tile and safely use as a trivet?

Tags: polyurethane

I would like to hand paint ceramic wall tiles to use as a food trivets. If I coat the tiles with polyurethane, to prevent the paint from chipping off, will it be safe to use as a trivet for hot pans or will the heat cause damage? I read the comments about wooden trivets but tile is not porous like wood is. If it's not a good idea, what type of coating should I use instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The clearcoat won't buy you anything for temperature resistance. It's not like you can put a high-temp clearcoat over a low-temp-vulnerable paint and have that work out.  Both the paint and the clearcoat will need to be high-temperature rated, since it'll be encountering worst-case 400F/200C or so from the bottom of a fry pan.

By the way, you need more words.  You're cutting off the noun, like using the word "cell" to mean "cell phone" or "built-in" to mean "built-in cabinets".  This doen't work with polyurethane because it is ambiguous - you have polyurethane paint, polyurethane stain, polyurethane sheeting, polyurethane panels (glass) etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use polyurethane to coat a painted wall tile and safely use as a
>   trivet?

No, it won't be heat resistant.

But, you can make something really durable by using appropriate coatings and firing in a kiln. Very few people have their own kiln, but there are "make your own pottery" businesses. You paint, they fire. There are many in my area.